# ANTLR4 Mismatch in simple grammar

Tags: c#, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I am using the latest version of Antlr (4.3) to parse this simple source file. I'm using the Visual Studio add-in, but that should not have anything to do with my problem.

Source file:

```
OBJECT Codeunit 80 Sales-Post
{
  OBJECT-PROPERTIES
  {
    Date=11/12/10;
    Time=12:00:00;
    Version List=NAVW16.00.10,NAVBE6.00.01;
  }
}
```

This should be pretty straightforward to parse, but I keep getting 2 errors while parsing:

```
line 1:16 mismatched input '80' expecting DOCUMENT_ID
line 5:4 mismatched input 'Date' expecting {DOCUMENT_PROPERTY_ID, '}'}
```

Complete grammar:

```
grammar Cal;

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */
document
    : document_header OPEN_BRACE document_content CLOSE_BRACE
    ;

document_header
    : OBJECT_DEFINITION DOCUMENT_TYPE DOCUMENT_ID DOCUMENT_NAME
    ;

document_content
    : document_properties
    ;

document_properties
    : OBJECT_PROPERTIES OPEN_BRACE document_property* CLOSE_BRACE
    ;

document_property
    : DOCUMENT_PROPERTY_ID EQ DOCUMENT_PROPERTY_VALUE LINE_TERM
    ;


/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */
OBJECT_PROPERTIES
    : 'OBJECT-PROPERTIES'
    ;

OBJECT_DEFINITION
    : 'OBJECT'
    ;

DOCUMENT_TYPE
    : 'Codeunit'
    | 'Table'
    ;

DOCUMENT_PROPERTY_VALUE
    : ([0-9a-zA-Z]|'_'|'-'|'.'|'/'|','|':')+
    ;

DOCUMENT_PROPERTY_ID
    : 'Date'
    | 'Time'
    | 'Version List'
    ;

DOCUMENT_ID
    : [0-9]+
    ;

DOCUMENT_NAME
    : ID
    ;

OPEN_BRACE
    : '{'
    ;

CLOSE_BRACE
    : '}'
    ;

LINE_TERM
    : ';'
    ;

EQ
    : '='
    ;

ID
    : ([a-zA-Z]|'_'|'-')+
    ;

INT
    : [0-9]+
    ;

WS
    : [ \t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

NEWLINE
    :'\r'? '\n' -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;
```

This is the output of the token stream (tokens are surrounded with '<>':

```
<OBJECT> < > <Codeunit> < > <80> < > <Sales-Post> <
> <{> <
> <  > <OBJECT-PROPERTIES> <
> <  > <{> <
> <    > <Date> <=> <11/12/10> <;> <
> <    > <Time> <=> <12:00:00> <;> <
> <    > <Version List> <=> <NAVW16.00.10,NAVBE6.00.01> <;> <
> <  > <}> <
> <}> <<EOF>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ANTLR, when two lexer rules can match the same token (of the same length), the rule that appears first wins.

`80` can be matched by `DOCUMENT_ID`, but also by `DOCUMENT_PROPERTY_VALUE` and `INT`, so just reorder these rules here.

You have the same problem here with `DOCUMENT_PROPERTY_ID` which is below `DOCUMENT_PROPERTY_VALUE` (both can match `Date`).

I suggest you put `DOCUMENT_PROPERTY_VALUE` just above `WS`: most specific rules (ie keywords) go first, and broader rules last.

You also have to get rid of `DOCUMENT_ID` or `INT`, as they have the same definition. One of them will never match. You don't seem to use `INT` in the parser, so just remove the rule.

Comment: I'd also suggest that adding semantic meaning like in `DOCUMENT_ID`, `DOCUMENT_NAME` should be done in parser rules and not in lexer rules. As a rule of thumb: if you cannot decide if `10` is a `DOCUMENT_ID` or a plain `INT`, don't make the decision in the lexer which is quite ignorant of context and wait for the decision until parse time.